# Is it possible to set VS to open XAML and XAML.cs file side by side by default

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, maui

I am working on a MAUI app and I often get lost between files while switching to XAML and code behind. I was working on a laptop screen so I didn't have many option but now that I have a large monitor I am able to display 2 code files side by side.

What would be really practical is to have Visual Studio automatically display each xaml and xaml.cs file as one, as shown on the attached screenshot. Is there a way to do that or maybe do you have some tricks/plugins to keep the work on XAML files organized ?

I am using Visual Studio Community 2022.

[image]

Comment: I do it manually like that, too. I don't think there is a way to do this automatically, because even a VS add-in would need to have some way to know about the split editor.

Comment: I navigate this confusion with excellent feature on a VS extension I've been using for 20 years called "Visual Assist".  It has a feature called "OpenCorrespondingFile"  that will toggle you between all sorts of file pairs like this.  Between .XAML and .XAML.CS as well as in C++ between .H and .CPP. and other technologies.   I cannot live without it.  I just hooked up a convenient hot-key to it (I use ALT+A) and go back and forth instantly.  I think it's better than side-by-side.    Sadly you have to pay for it but it does have a trial.  It's in the "Extension" dialog if you search

Comment: Oh that one sounds nice, that's exactly the kind of stuff I was referencing to I'll give that a try thanks!